# regular expression @generated

Tags: regex, expression

i have the following code:

```
/**
* @generated
*/
public class foo ...

/**
* @generated
*/
public class bar...

public class interesting
```

I am interested in those signatures, which haven't the @generated tag. Therefore I was trying to write a regular expression. But I can't get it working... Can you please help me ?

```
([\^*][/]\r\n)p
```

matches all elements with the @generated tag, but how can I get those withouth the @generated tag ?!

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the language that you use to extract the data?

Comment: Your regular expression does not match [anything](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%5B%5C^*%5D%5B%2F%5D%5Cr%5Cn)p&input=%2F**%0A*%20%40generated%0A*%2F%0Apublic%20class%20foo%20...%0A%0A%2F**%0A*%20%40generated%0A*%2F%0Apublic%20class%20bar...%0A%0Apublic%20class%20interesting%0A). Which regexp syntax do you use?

Comment: honestly I don't know, I use Notepad++ with search option "regular expressions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with regex `(?<!@generated\n\*\/\n)(public class .*)` and if needed to add some `\s` to negative lookbehind `(?<! ... )`. Lookbehind has to be fix pattern, so you need to adjust it exactly without `\s*` or some other variable length pattern.

Comment: but your code finds all occurences of \@generated not ... What I want to have is only those "public class..." lines where NO \@generated is

Comment: @matthias - regex works fine - see http://ideone.com/Rh07l. You probably have one whitespace character behind `*/`, so then you need to adjust regex to `(?<!@generated\n\*\/\s\n)(public class .*)`